# Combine find, grep and xargs with printf

Tags: unix, grep, find, printf, xargs

I have a find command combined with exec grep and a printf option :

```
find  -L /home/blast/dirtest -maxdepth 3  **-exec grep -q  "pattern" {} \;**  -printf '%y/#/%TY-%Tm-%Td %TX/#/%s/#/%f/#/%l/#/%h\n' 2> /dev/null
```

Result :

```
f/#/2018-01-01 10:00:00/#/191/#/filee.xml/#//#//home/blast/dirtest/01/05
```

I need the printf to get all the desired file informations at once (date, type size etc)

The above command works fine. But the exec option is too slow comparing to xargs.

I tryed to do the same with xarg but I did not succeed. 
Any Idea on how to acheive that ?  using the xargs command keeping the desired printf or similar .

Thanks

Comment: How do you know `-exec` is slower than `xargs` if `xargs` didn't work?

Comment: @jhnc I can pipe the xargs command with  "find", but I did not know how to combine it with the printf ( printf is an option of find). for the performance , there are a lots of tests on the internet that confirm to speed of xargs comparing to -exec.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is:

```
find  -L /home/blast/dirtest -maxdepth 3 \
    -exec grep -q  "pattern" {} \; \
    -printf '%y/#/%TY-%Tm-%Td %TX/#/%s/#/%f/#/%l/#/%h\n' 2> /dev/null
```

This invokes a new `grep` process for each file.

If you are using GNU utilities, you can reduce the number of `grep` processes by something like:

```
(
    format=\''%y/#/%TY-%Tm-%Td %TX/#/%s/#/%f/#/%l/#/%h\n'\'

    find -L /home/blast/dirtest -maxdepth 3 -print0 |\
    xargs -0 grep -l -Z "pattern" |\
    xargs -0 sh -c 'find "$@" -printf '"$format" --
) 2>/dev/null
```

- for clarity, store the formatstring in a variable
- use `-print0` / `-0` / `-Z` options to enable null-delimited data
- generate initial filelist with `find`
- filter on `"pattern"` with `grep` (use of `xargs` minimises the number of times `grep` gets called)
- feed the filtered filelist into another `xargs` to run a minimal number of `find -printf`
- in second `xargs`, call a subshell so that extra arguments can be appended (`find` requires the paths to precede the operators)
- dummy second argument (`--`) to the `sh -c` invocation prevents the first filename being lost due to assignment to `$0`

Comment: I live, sometimes I learn.  You're right about the required semantics.

Comment: I prefer this solution over the first answer. even with multi piping of xargs the performane is better. But I v found that the -exec option has the ability to run the command only once. as I mentioned in my answer below

Comment: Yes, instead of `find ... | xargs grep ... | xargs ...`, you can do `find ... -exec grep ... '{}' \+ | xargs ...`. Performance should be similar. It's probably a matter of taste which to use.

Answer (score 1):

To do it exactly how you want:

```
find  -L /home/blast/dirtest/ -maxdepth 3 \
    -printf '%p@%y/#/%TY-%Tm-%Td %TX/#/%s/#/%f/#/%l/#/%h\n' \
    > tmp.out
cut -d@ -f1 tmp.out \
    | xargs grep -l "pattern" 2>/dev/null \
    | sed 's/^/^/; s/$/@/' \
    | grep -f /dev/stdin tmp.out \
    | sed 's/^.*@//'
```

This operates under the assumption that you have no character `@` in your file names.

What it does is avoid the grep at first and just dump all the files with the requested metadata to a temporary file.

But it also prefixes each line with the full path (`%p@`).

Then we extract (`cut`) the full paths out of this list and list the files which contains the pattern (`xargs grep`).

We then use `sed` to prefix each such file name with `^` and suffix it with `@`, which makes it a greppable pattern in our `tmp.out` file.

Then we use this pattern (`grep -f /dev/stdin`) to extract only those paths from the big list in `tmp.out`.

Now all that's left is to remove the artificial full path we prefixed using the last `sed` command.

Seeing how you used `/home`, there's a good chance you're on Linux, which, if you're willing to accept some output format changes, allows you to do it somewhat more elegantly:

```
find -L /home/blast/dirtest/ -maxdepth 3 \
    | xargs grep -l "pattern" 2>/dev/null \
    | xargs stat --printf '%F/#/%y/#/%s/#/%n\n'
```

The output of `stat --printf` is different from that of `find -printf` (and from that of MacOS' `stat -f`), but it's the same information.

Do note, however, that because you passed `-L` to find, and you're grepping the result:

1. The results are limited to file types which can be grepped, so they will never be directories, links, etc..
2. If you stumble upon a broken link, it will not be in the output because it cannot be grepped.

Answer (score 0):

I'v found an intresting thing about the -exec option.
We could run the grep once using the exec with the plus-sign (+)

```
-exec command {} +
              This variant of the -exec option runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the  total
              number  of  invocations  of  the  command  will be much less than the number of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its command
              lines.  Only one instance of ’{}’ is allowed within the command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.
```

That means if I change this :

```
-exec grep -l 'pattern'  {} \;
```

By this ( replace the semicolon with the plus signe ):

```
-exec grep -l 'pattern'  {} \+
```

Will improve the performance significantly.

Then I can pipe only one xargs for the format printing needs only.